# accepting multiple user inputs separated by a space in python and append them to a list

Tags: python, list

How can I accept multiple user inputs separated by a space? I don't know the number of inputs, but I do know they are all ints.

Here's some example inputs:

```
13213 412 8143
12 312
1321 142 9421 9 29 319
```

I know can do this if I know the number of inputs beforehand, but I'm having trouble making this generic. I could just ask the user to input how many groups of ints he will input:

```
inputs = int(raw_input("Enter number of raw inputs "))
num = []
for i in xrange(1, inputs):
    num.append(raw_input('Enter the %s number: '))
```

But I am looking for a more elegant solution that doesn't require asking the user 2 questions.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
s = raw_input("Please enter your numbers: ")

mynums = [int(i) for i in s.split()]
# OR
mynums = map(int, s.split())
```

Comment: @inspectorG4dget thanks! i uped both of you, i have to be fair although the oneliner is much more elegant

Comment: +1 to both of you -- @inspectorG4dget special recognition for "argv!"

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
nums = [int(i) for i in raw_input("Enter space separated inputs: ").split()]
```

Answer (score 0):

for python 2.x

**x,y = map(int,raw_input().split())**

it take two variable x and y of int type separated by space and you can replace int with your desired type

for python 3.x

**x,y = input().split()**

it takes two variables x and y of string type separated by space and you have to convert explicitly

Answer (score 0):

`x,y=map(int,input().split())`  #this will take input separated by space and map #into int

Comment: I don't see any tag or comment for what language this is.  Can you clarify the question?