# Python 3.5.1 - read multiple integers on the same input line into a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

I'm using python 3.5.1 and running my file through command prompt on windows. The arguments are being passed after the program is run; ie the program prompts for input based on a previously generated list.

I'm looking to read in multiple numbers on the same line separated by spaces.  Python 2.X it wouldn't have been an issue with raw_input but this is proving to be a challenge.

```
selection = list(map(int,input("Enter items to archive (1 2 etc):").split(",")))
```

If I enter two different numbers on the same line:

> Enter items to archive (1 2 etc):29 30  Traceback (most recent call
>   last):   File "G:\Learning\Python\need_to_watch.py", line 15, in
>   
>        selection = list(map(int,input("Enter items to archive (1 2 etc):").split(",")))   File "", line 1
>        29 30
>            ^ SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

I gave up on a single line and tried just doing it in a loop but I get a different error

```
data=[]
while True:
        entry = int(input('Item number : '))
        data.append(entry)
        if entry == 'q':
            break
```

It tries to evaluate 'q' as a variable even though I haven't eval()'d anything.

This question says to just use input().split() but it would appear that this no longer works....
[accepting multiple user inputs separated by a space in python and append them to a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404946/accepting-multiple-user-inputs-seperated-by-a-space-in-python-and-append-them-to)

I could try and catch the EOF exception, but that doesn't seem like the right way to do it, nor should it be necessary.

Answer (score 3):

```
entry = input('Enter items: ')
entry = entry.split()
entry = list(map(int, entry))
print(entry)
```

Or more concisely:

```
entry = list(map(int, input('Enter items: ').split()))
print(entry)
```

Comment: This is the common answer that everyone recommends and I have already tried it (see OP).  After entering two numbers, it gives me: "SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing"  This works if I use the interpreter, but not if I run it from a .py file.

Comment: What exactly is the input that is not working for you?

Comment: If I type in "1 2" without quotes, I get an EOF error.  If I type in "1 2 3" without quotes I get an invalid syntax error.  It just doesn't like spaces when not run in an interpreter.

Comment: I am running it with `python filename.py` from the console and it works with the given input.

Comment: Throwing "python" in front of the filename has it work now too.  It was using 2.7's interpreter not the 3.5.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass arguments to a python script, you may want to take a look at argparse instead: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser() 
parser.add_argument('integers', type=int, nargs='+')

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.integers)

python script.py 1 2 3 4
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: I'm passing the arguments inside the program.  It scans a directory for files matching specifics and prints them all out 1-###.  Then it prompts for the user to input which numbers to perform an action too.  In the example, I wanted to tell the program to do something with entries 29 and 30.

Answer (score 1):

You try to evaluate everything as an `int` which is obviously not going to work. Try this instead:

```
data = []

while True:
    entry = input('Item number : ')
    if entry == 'q':
        break

    try:
        data.append(int(entry))
    except:
        print("Not a valid number")
```

Comment: Instead of `try/except`, you can use `isdigit()`. `if entry.is_digit(): data.append(q)` `elif entry == 'q': break`